# making key on preapring release ready apk: android

Tags: android, eclipse, release, sign

I have the app ready so trying to sign it. I read the dev docs. Am using eclipse and adt so started using export. Am able to export a sample app. While exporting they says to have the key. I have created a new file and proceeded and finally I got the output apk. Once whn I opened the key file, I cant read anything. So I am confused.. Will it be readable?? or like the same? Please tell me about the certificate they are mentioning on signing the app, is this same as the one, the file I have created?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: The keystore file you mean ? Of course it is not readable this is the point. It containt the keys of al the applications you have signed it with.

Comment: Thanks. so I guess I can use the same file for other app too right?

Comment: Just one more.. Is there any certificates I have to have to sign it? Or where is the need of certificte on whole the process of uploading an app to store? @Yume117 thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can but note that if you "lose" this file or if it is corrupted you will lose the only way to publish new update to your applicationS. So keep the keytore AND it's pass word in a secure place. Maybe several copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once whn I opened the key file, I cant read anything. So I am confused.. Will it be readable??

Your keystore file (e.g. mykeystore.keystore) should not be readable in a text editor or other such program.

> Please tell me about the certificate they are mentioning on signing the app, is this same as the one, the file I have created??

Once you have finished signing your APK using your keystore (see [Signing your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)), the APK will contain a `META-INF` directory that contains a `CERT.RSA` file, which is the application's certificate. You don't need to worry about this file at all, and it is automatically generated by keytool when you sign your APK.

Your private key (see [Obtain a Private Key](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert)) is also referred to as your signing certificate, and is what is stored in the keystore. This is the key that you use to sign your application. After you have generated this key using keytool, you shouldn't need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: thanks @Tanis. Do we need to use this certificate on any other process on uploading this apk?

Comment: Once you have signed your APK, you do not need to use it again until you are ready to release another version of your application. The certificate is not needed for uploading a signed APK to the Play Store.